# How to pass value to web page form after using window.open

Tags: javascript, forms, function, onload

I am trying to login to an auction website, with the ultimate goal of placing bids at a specific time without being physically in front of the computer.

How to I pass values to the webpage form, and login to the site?

The login page loads after hitting submit, but the input from exampleInputEmail1 and exampleInputPassword1 is not passed to the webpage.

I thought this might have to do with onload, but no luck so far.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  function openGoodWill() {

    var newWindow;
    newWindow = window.open('https://www.shopgoodwill.com/SignIn');
    newWindow.onload = function(){
    window.document.getElementById('Username').value = 'exampleInputEmail1';
    window.document.getElementById('Password').value = 'exampleInputPassword1';
    window.document.getElementById('login-submit').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));
}
  }
</script>
<body>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button onclick="openGoodWill()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
```

The login page loads after hitting submit, but the input from exampleInputEmail1 and exampleInputPassword1 is not passed to the webpage.

Comment: You could try to find the login API of that website. Try to call the login API directly and reload page.

Answer (score 0):

To pass from javascript using `window.open`,

> For Non-Sensitive Info

**GET**
you can transfer data with URL using `GET`method.

```
window.open('your_site?data1='+data1+'&data2='+data2,'_SELF');
```

**Cookies**

You can save data in cookie, Then after redirect, Again you can read from cookies.

**Local Storage**

Like cookie, You can store data in `Local Storage` using Javascript. Then you can read from re-directed site.

*Example :*

Write

```
localStorage.setItem('userId','10036656');
```

Read

```
var userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
```

> **But In Your Case**

To handle sensitive information like Login-In details. Please handle with server directly.

You can use `Form Submit`

**OR**

Please use `AJAX Request` using Javascript. 
[AJAX Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)